# jsrender picasa

Tags: picasa, jsrender

I can't figure this out, I am trying to get the pictures from googles picasa in json format.
and using jsrender to render html out.

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargo/6425U/1/) for you to look at.

it's is giving me undefined, and I used Chrome Developer Tools to analyze the data.
I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is trying to access `model.author.name` which does not exist in the json data. To display the list of author names, change that part of your template to:

```
{{for author}}                        
    <h2>{{:name.$t}} </h2>
{{/for}}
```

To access other information from the JSON data, use a similar method to loop over the collections.